# How do I check for available memory in C#?

Tags: c#

I am implementing an LRU cache. While putting data into the cache, I need to check whether I have enough memory for the new data and call the cache eviction routine if there isnt. How do I check for available memory?

Answer (score 7):

> I need to check whether I have enough memory for the new data and call the cache eviction routine if there isn't.

This is an extremely bad idea. You should not do this.

As Raymond Chen often says: what happens when two things try to do that?  Suppose you have two components in the same address space on two different threads. Now you have the worst kind of race conditions: both components ask if there is enough memory. Suppose there is enough memory for one of them but not both. What magical force tells one of them to do a cache eviction but not the other one? There is no such force. Both will attempt to allocate memory, and one will fail.

Even without two things, the fundamental idea is just bad. The idea here is to walk as close to the edge of a cliff as you possibly can, but not so close that you fall off the cliff. **This is a recipe for falling off a cliff.** You should never be *anywhere even vaguely close* to the edge of that cliff. You should look at that two billion bytes of virtual address space and think "wow, that is freakin' enormous. There's no way I'm ever going to come even close to running out of that."  If you do think that you might be running out then you need to move some of your work into another process, or use memory mapped files and manage your own virtual memory.

So let's take a step back. A cache is a performance optimization that works by trading more memory usage for less time. The question you should be asking yourself is *what level of performance is barely acceptable to my customer?*  Quantify that. Then ask first, *is performance without a cache already acceptable?* If it is then you don't need to burn memory; you're already good enough. If it's not good enough then try to come up with a fixed size cache that gives good enough performance. Only if you cannot do that should you go to more advanced techniques.

A common technique for large caches is to put the garbage collector in charge of the cache: make the cache a cache of *weak references*. A weak reference is a reference that does not *prevent* garbage collection but does not *encourage* it either; basically, the GC will collect some weak-referenced objects if it feels like it is running low on memory. Your cache logic is basically: cache everything. When it's time to search the cache, ask the weak reference if it has been collected or not. If the answer is yes, remove the weak reference from the cache. If the answer is no, turn it back into a strong reference and use the object. This technique works, but it has its down sides: namely, you've just put the CLR GC team in charge of tuning your cache. They might have different ideas about what makes a good cache policy than you do.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are asking, but in your case, I'd go and check [MemoryFailPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.memoryfailpoint.aspx)